# Special integrals

Tags: real-analysis

There are special integrals such as the logarithmic integral and exponential integrals. I want to know if there are primitives for such integrals. If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, there are primitives. No, they can't be expressed in terms of exponentials, logarithms, trig functions, etc.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson , So how are they expressed then?

Comment: @Badshah: as integrals.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan but why cant they be expressed as logarithms exponentials etc..

Comment: @Badshah, the proof requires some theories such as differential Galois theory, which I know not much about. But maybe you can google on it and find some materials regarding this problem such as [this](http://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.claymath.org%2Fprograms%2Foutreach%2Facademy%2FLectureNotes05%2FConrad.pdf&ei=61qnUNeWHsLTiwKsoIG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHmZfy65Jw664Q1Dk7Pq0ZoJtCaZw&sig2=LVhuEcS2YSq1iFwV_S4C0Q).

Comment: @Badshah: see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple starting point (as indicated by Qiaochu) is [Liouville's theorem (or 'principle')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) based on [differential algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) and was extended with the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

This last link should clarify some of the ideas used :

1. the only new term appearing during an integration (i.e. that was not in the integrand) is a linear combination of logarithms (because logarithms alone may disappear during differentiation...)
2. exponentials $e^f$ had to be in the integrand first (since differentiation doesn't make them disappear) and will reappear as $h\,e^f$ (of course subtle points exist like considering $\sqrt{x}=e^{\,\large{\ln(x)/2}}\cdots$)
3. differentiation of an [algebraic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) $\theta$ (i.e. there is a polynomial $P(\theta)=0$) will give a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) $\dfrac {d(\theta)}{e(\theta)}$ with $\,d$ and $e\,$ two polynomials.

These 3 ideas will provide logarithmic, exponential and algebraic extensions to the differential algebra (starting for example with the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$) that will give all the [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

An excellent tutorial about this is ["Symbolic Integration"](http://www-sop.inria.fr/cafe/Manuel.Bronstein/publications/issac98.pdf) from Manuel Bronstein.

Geddes, Czapor and Labahn's book ["Algorithms for Computer Algebra"](https://books.google.com/books?id=B9tC7DOX_oUC&pg=PA512#v=onepage&q&f=false) is very clear too.

---

Now let's use these ideas to study $\;\displaystyle\int\frac {e^x}x\,dx$.

From a more precise version of $2.$ a primitive must be of type $\ I(x)=h(x)\,e^x\;$ with $h(x)$ a rational function. Let's suppose this and differentiate $\,I(x)$ :
$$(h'(x)+h(x))\,e^x=\frac {e^x}x$$
so that we need :
$$h'(x)+h(x)=\frac 1x$$
We supposed $h$ rational so that it may be decomposed in simple elements but $h'(x)$ can't give $\dfrac 1x$ so that $\dfrac 1x$ must be part of $h(x)$. In this case $h'(x)$ will create a term $-\dfrac 1{x^2}$ that must be compensated by a $\dfrac 1{x^2}$ term inside $h(x)$ that will generate a $-\dfrac 2{x^3}$ term... This process clearly doesn't end !

The same method could be used for the sine integral : $\;\displaystyle\int \frac {\sin(x)}x\,dx\,$ simply by writing $\ \sin(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.
(this [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative/265884#265884) was presented by Matthew P Wiener in an [old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/sci.math/VfGyqeTIcB0/cTFxvET81UMJ) at sci.math : recommended reading too !)

Concerning the logarithmic integral we have $\ \operatorname{li}(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(\ln(x))\ $ so that the non-elementary proof for the one should apply for the other as well.

Comment: There's a wrong $dz$, and $z$ in your equations.

Comment: Thanks to care @YoTengoUnLCD (corrected) !