# How to evaluate $\int {\frac{{\cos {x^3}}}{x}dx}$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate
$$\int {\frac{{\cos {x^3}}}{x}dx}?$$ Maple evaluates this as
$$\frac{{{\text{Ci}}({x^3})}}{3}.$$
**Edit**: If this cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions, is there a general strategy which allows us to deduce that this is the case?

Comment: Why downvote? Care to comment?

Comment: You may need to read [this](http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/ksda/papers/churchill.pdf).

Comment: Concerning the edit : just some days earlier we had the same kind of [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239105/special-integrals/239854#239854). Set $z=x^3$ to get $\ \frac 13\int \frac{\cos(z)}z dz$ and use the demonstration there for $\int \frac{\sin(z)}z dz$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I = \int \dfrac{\cos(x^3)}{x} dx = \dfrac13 \int \dfrac{\cos(x^3)}{x^3} (3x^2)dx = \dfrac13 \int \dfrac{\cos(x^3)}{x^3} d(x^3) = \dfrac{\text{Ci}(x^3)}{3} + \text{constant}$$
There is no expression for the above integral in terms of "elementary functions". If the limits of the integral are from $-a$ to $a$, the Cauchy principal value of the integral is $0$ since the integrand is an odd function.

Comment: Yes, but what is that in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Can someone explain what is "Ci"?

Comment: @learner $\operatorname{Ci}(\xi)$ stands for *cosine integral*.

Comment: @glebovg thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CosIntegral.html

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosineintegral%28x%29

That means there is a real part and a imaginary part.

Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with Wolfram or Wolframalpha.