# Question on integration of $x^{x}$

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate $\displaystyle\int x^{x} \, dx$.

For this I am taking

$$\begin{align}
x^{x}&=t\\
\log {x^{x}}&=\log {t}\\
x\log x&=\log t\\
e^{x\log x}&=t\\
\end{align}$$

Then I am stuck! Please make suggestions on how to do this example.

Comment: This doesn't have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: for bound $0-1$ this does have interesting property. Check [this out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: As indicated by Potato this integral is not elementary : see this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative).

Answer (score 3):

See [Power Tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) for a note on how $x^x$ has not indefinite integral in terns of elementary functions, but the definite integral $\int_0^1 x^x dx$ does have an answer.