# what is the$ \int \sin (x^2) \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$u$ substitution doesnt work. I don't see any connection with the Weierstrass substitution either. integration by parts results in a infinite integral series.

Comment: take a look to [the Fresnel Integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: is it possible to express this as a fourier series and than integrate that function?

Comment: [Fred Rickey](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/82512/fred-rickey) has pointed out that the association of the substitution $u=\tan(x/2)$ with Weierstrass is a mistake.  It goes back at least to Euler and no one seems to have found any evidence that Weierstrass ever mentioned it.  I wonder if the error came only from Stewart's calculus books?

Comment: really now? That's something to ponder upon. I just read somewhere this is also a elliptical integral any explanation on that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this integral does not have a solution in terms of elementary functions. But, you can solve it using series methods. For instance, since

$$ \sin x = \sum \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$ \text{then} \; \; \sin (x^2) = \sum \frac{(-1)^n x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$ \int \sin (x^2) = \int \sum \frac{(-1)^n x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum \frac{(-1)^n x^{4n+3}}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)} + K $$

Comment: what is "elementary"?

Comment: the well know functions from calculus: the trigonometric, exponentials, etc

Comment: so there are some functions you cannot simply integrate? so how are you supposed to know before d oing so much work that it can't be done? there are nastier functions than this one but yet they turned out ti be integratable.

Comment: just experience will tell you. There is neither magic, nor mistery. Just Experience.

Comment: It can also be proved, see [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) and [this question on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral) or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative)

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica returns:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x\right)$$

So, unless you consider Fresnel Sine to be an elementary function, that explains your troubles.

Comment: It is not a matter of whether or not you consider a function to be elementary. An elementary function is a well defined concept not subject to opinion.

Comment: @JonClaus Thanks for the terminological enlightenment! As you see from my profile, I am new to this math stuff...

Answer (score 1):

By Geogebra, the result is:

[image]

But if you do it in python with below code:

```
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import display

a = Integral(sin(x**2), x)
b = Eq(a,a.doit())
display(b)
```

The result is:

[image]

But I don't know how to understand the difference.