# Computing the integral $\int_1^n\frac{1}{(\ln x)^p}dx$

Tags: integration

What is the approach I should have? How can I calculate this integral? I put it into Mathematica in order to get a step by step solution, but Mathematica does not give a step by step explanation. The Wolfram solution incorporates a Gamma function but I don't know it.

Do I need to know this Gamma function to proceed?

$$\int_1^n\frac{1}{(\ln x)^p}dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: I tried substitution and then integration by parts... But I could not solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you *need* special functions to be able to express this integral in closed form, and without them you cannot. The reason for this is that [some integrals cannot be expressed solely in terms of elementary functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative/265884#265884).

Answer (score 1):

You do need Gamma function after substitution $t=\ln x$ and even more. Mathematica gives a reslt but in trems of special functions. 
$$
\log ^{-p}(n) \left(p \Gamma (-p) (-\log
   (n))^p-\log (n) E_p(-\log (n))\right)
$$
Here $E_p$ is an [exponential integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).