# How to integrate $\sin (x^2)$ function?

Tags: integration

what are the steps to integrate the following without using numerical methods-

$$ \int \sin(x^2)\,dx.$$

Comment: This is a special function : a [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) see too this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Comment: The antiderivative of $sin(x^2)$ is not an elementary function.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680478/list-of-functions-not-integrable-in-elementary-terms).

Comment: Matthew Wiener proved it non elementary [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative/265884#265884).

Comment: If you're averse to using special functions like the Fresnel integral, then you must resort to numerical quadrature, and for evaluating the Fresnel integral numerically, you must use numerics anyway. But for symbolic purposes, the Fresnel result is fine. So, which?

Comment: You might also have a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251083/some-way-to-integrate-sinx2) and other [questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/251083). However, they are mainly about $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2) dx$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Use:
>
> $$\sin\left(x^2\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\left(x^2\right)^{1+2n}}{(1+2n)!}$$

So, we get:

$$\int\sin\left(x^2\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\left(x^2\right)^{1+2n}}{(1+2n)!}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+2n)!}\int\left(x^2\right)^{1+2n}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Now, use:

$$\int a^b\space\text{d}a=\frac{a^{b+1}}{b+1}+\text{C}$$

---

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+2n)!}\int x^{2+4n}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{3+4n}}{(4n+3)(1+2n)!}+\text{C}$$