# Integration but with both the transformation and differential forms of a function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Let $\int f(x) dx$ be $F(x)+C$, evaluate:
$$\int^t_0 f(x+T)F(t-x)dx$$

Where $T$ is a constant. Integration by parts come to mind but how do I deal with the additional terms inside the two functions?

Edit:
What if we let $F(x)=1-e^{-(\frac{x}{n})^b}$, where $n$ and $b$ are additional constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x+T\neq \pm (t-x)$, it is **impossible** to find a result without an integration sign in it. Let's do the calculations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^t{f}\left( x+T \right) F\left( t-x \right) dx
\\
&=\int_T^{t+T}{f}\left( x+T \right) F\left( t-x \right) d\left( x+T \right) 
\\
&=\int_T^{t+T}{F\left( t-x \right) dF\left( x+T \right)}
\\
&=F\left( t-x \right) F\left( x+T \right) \mid_{T}^{t+T}-\int_T^{t+T}{F\left( x+T \right) dF\left( t-x \right)}
\\
&=F\left( t+2T \right) F\left( -T \right) -F\left( t-T \right) F\left( 2T \right) +\int_T^{t+T}{f\left( t-x \right) F\left( x+T \right) dx}
\end{aligned}
$$
And finally we **cannot** eliminate **anything** to simply further.

Comment: Will the definition of F(x) help?

Comment: What do you mean by  definition? If you can give a concrete form of $F(x)$, then it may be possible.

Comment: Concrete form added

Comment: It seems that it won't have elementary representations... See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680478/list-of-functions-not-integrable-in-elementary-terms)

Comment: Does that mean that I can only compute that expression numerically?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.