# Is there a quick effective method to figure out the best possible substitution to perform indefinite integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

When solving integration question it becomes cumbersome to find the right substitution term so that it can aid the integration problem. Would like to know to any logic that can aid us easily find the best substitution term for the indefinite imtegration problems.

Comment: In my opinion, the best approach is to find the right Real Analysis text book that provides the correct substitution to use for integration problems that follow a pattern.  My personal experience is that **not** trying to *re-invent the* *wheel* has saved me much time and effort.  I have found that often, the best substitution to use will seem counter-intuitive **before** you have been properly trained/educated.

Comment: Practice is very helpful, assuming the integral can be done at all with a substitution

Comment: For many Calculus I level integrals,
A. Pick the largest expression whose derivative is multiplied elsewhere in the integrand.
B. Know your derivatives very thoroughly.

Comment: I just asked the question in a way it would help me  for engineering entrance preparation in India. So this is where you basically have problems of the level freshman year abroad. Thankyou for the valuable comments.

Comment: This probably isn’t the answer you want to hear, but you just gotta practice. There will always be multiple correct ways to you could perform a given integral. Try as many ways as possible for yourself during practice to see which are easiest/shortest.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4134102/888233) I asked before.