# What is the value of $\int x^x~dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am struggling with this puzzle.

**Question 1.** Is it possible to determine the value of the indefinite integral $\int x^x~dx$ explicitly?

By "explicit" I mean without power series.

**Question 2.** What are known theorems in the following form?

"$\int x^x~dx$ is not expressible by an expression given by functions in a family $\mathfrak{F}$" e.g. $\mathfrak{F}=\{\sin, \cos, \text{polynomials}\}$

Comment: If Mathematica can't do it, then likely, no one can: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=x%5Ex&random=false

Comment: I don't see how you can prove that you cannot explicitly take an integral.  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that an anti-derivative exists for every integrable function--just because you cannot do it analytically doesn't mean _a_ function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jared By "impossibility" I mean non-existence of an expression given by a set of "fundamental functions" e.g. polynomials, sin, cos, etc.

Comment: Define fundamental functions, because I'm not sure I would consider $\sin$, $\cos$, $\sqrt{}$, etc. any more "fundamental" than merely stating $\int x^x dx = \text{Jared}(x) + C$ where $\frac{d\text{Jared}}{dx} = x^x$.

Comment: It should be theoretically possible to write this as a power series, however getting an explicit form of $x^x$ would be next to impossible (since you have $e^{x\ln(x)} = \sum \frac{x^i\ln^i(x))}{i!}$)

Comment: There's a bit of a problem with this function for negative values of $x$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative) should help.

Comment: @Jared : Great idea to invent the function Jared(x). So great that it was already done (Unfortunately with a different name ! ) : See the paper "The Sophomores Dream Function" published on Sribd : http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents . I hope that an agreement will be achieved for a common name for this magnificent function.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) and [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29), the primitive of this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Nor can it be expressed in terms of special functions, such as [Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) or [error functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), etc. either, since $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Indefinite intgerals of the form $\displaystyle{\int \mathrm{f}(x)\, \mathrm{d}x}$ do not have a *value*.

The "answer" to an integral like this is a *function* and not a number. For example:

$$\int 3x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = x^3 + C$$

All of the function $x^3+C$ have the property that their derivatives, with respect to $x$, are $3x^2$.

It is definite integrals (and some infinite indefinite integrals) that take values. For example:

$$\int_1^2 3x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \left[x^3\right]_1^2 = 8 - 1 = 7$$

The basic difference is that definite integrals find areas and give numbers. Indefinite integrals find anti-derivatives and give functions. In most simple examples, we need to be able to find the anti-derivative to find an exact value for the area - as I did in the example above. However, in the case of $x^x$, the is no know anti-derivative. To prove this, you need to use [Picard–Vessiot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Vessiot_theory). This shows that there is no [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) anti-derivative.

However, it is possible to find the value of the definite integrals
$$\int_a^b x^x \, \mathrm{d}x$$
using numerical methods, e.g. the [Trapezium Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) or [Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule). These can be used to find a value that is correct to any desired degree of accuracy.

There are some indefinite integrals that take values, e.g.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1} = \pi$$

Comment: Still $\exists F:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}. \int_a^b x^x = F(b) - F(a)$.  The question is how do you prove $F$ is transcendental, which I guess Differential Galois Theory can be used to prove.

Comment: @Jared The question has been changed since I made my post.

Comment: I shouldn't use the term "transcendental" since this has a very restrictive definition (e.g. $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is transcendental).

Answer (score 1):

$x^x$ is an integrable function as already said a number of times. The question is to know if a closed form exists. As usual for special functions, no closed form exists until one is defined and referenced. They are some conditions to define a new special function but I will not discuss this point here : it should be outside the scope of the question.

About the search for antiderivatives of $x^x$, there is an amusing anecdote told in the introduction of the paper "The Sophomores Dream Function" published on Scribd :
http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents

By the way, $\int_0^X x^x \, \mathrm{d}x =$ Sphd$(1;X)$

Answer (score 0):

$\int x^x~dx=\int e^{x\ln x}~dx=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n(\ln x)^n}{n!}dx$

For $\int x^n(\ln x)^n~dx$ , where $n$ is any non-negative integers,

$\int x^n(\ln x)^n~dx$

$=\int(\ln x)^n~d\left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}d((\ln x)^n)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)x}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{nx^n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{n+1}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{n+1}d\left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\int\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}d\left(\dfrac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{n+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\int\dfrac{n(n-1)x^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-2}}{(n+1)^2x}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\int\dfrac{n(n-1)x^n(\ln x)^{n-2}}{(n+1)^2}dx$

$=\cdots\cdots$

$\vdots$

$\vdots$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times2)x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^n}-\int\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times1)x^n}{(n+1)^n}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times2)x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^n}+\dfrac{(-1)^n(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times1)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}+C$

$=\dfrac{(n+1)x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{(n+1)^2}-\dfrac{(n+1)nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}((n+1)n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times2)x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^{n+1}}+\dfrac{(-1)^n((n+1)n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times1)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(n+1)!x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+2}}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}n!x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$

$\therefore\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(x\ln x)}{n!}dx=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$

Hence $\int x^x~dx=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$