# Integral of $x^x$

Tags: integration

I can't find this integral around here, 
does anybody suggest how to calculate this integral?

$$
I = \int x^x dx.
$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably no closed form

Comment: Why do you suppose that a closed formula exists?

Comment: use $y=x^x$ (there is no closed form)

Comment: If there is a closed form, you'll probably get there by writing
$$x^x = \exp(x \ln x)$$
(this is how you can find it's derivative fairly easily)

Comment: Concerning a closed form this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative) may help. Approximations may be obtained using AlexR's comment as shown by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28x%5Ex%2Cx%29).

Answer (score 0):

This integral does not have a solution in terms of elementary functions. However a series approximation yields 
$$ \int x^x\ dx= \int e^{\ln x^x}\ dx = \int \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k\ln^k x}{k!}\ dx $$