# Any way to simplify $\int \sqrt{f'(x)} \mathrm{d} x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

Trying to calculate the length of some geodesic I came across an expression of the form
$$
\int \sqrt{f'(x)} \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which got me wondering if there is any way to simplify or calculate such integrals in general (where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is sufficiently regular).

**EDIT:** I'm looking for a simplification in terms on $f$. (Anti-)derivatives of $f$ and integral transforms of $f$ would be interesting too.

**EDIT 2:** The asymptotic expansion for the integral of a product 
$$ \int f g = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k f^{(k)} g^{(-1-k)} $$

@AmbretteOrrisey has given in the comments actually looks quite interesting (even if it is not very useful). I guess something similar for my expression would be nice, too.

Comment: Please make the question more specific. Otherwise I can just say $\int\sqrt{f'(x)}dx$ and be done with it. Are you specifying that the answer can only be in terms of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ and $\int f(x)dx$? What about $f(x^2)$ or $f''(x)$? Do you allow those?

Comment: @YiFan As I wrote in my edit, those are all fine. Basically you know all values of $f$ as well as of its derivatives and integrals.

Comment: So the simplification is $\int\sqrt{f'(x)}dx$. Done! Unless this expression is not actually allowed, in which case you must specify.

Comment: I feel like this would be a hell of a lot easier if we knew $f$ or $f'$. Like I get you want a general statement but I don't know of anything that would apply.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I'm no longer interested in the specific integral that gave me this idea, so there only is the general case.

Comment: No, there is in general no simple form for this.  It is a frustration of calculus teachers that there is only a short list of examples where the arc length of $y=f(x)$ can be computed explicitly.  Which is why all the calculus books have the same exercises for this.

Comment: Not likely - you generally don't get 'pleasant' theorems for integration of functions of general functions in the way you do for differentiation. There _might conceivably_ be some kind of infinite series that produces a tractable _asymptotic expansion_ in certain cases - as there is for the product of two functions - $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\operatorname{f^{(k)}}\operatorname{g^{(-1-k)}}$ ... but the way these integrals are generally done is on an ad hoc basis - broaching the properties of whatever particular function is the argument of the square-root function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for some sort of analog to $$\frac {\mathrm d(\sqrt {f'(x)})} {\mathrm dx} = \frac {f''(x)} {2 \sqrt{f'(x)}} $$

But for $\int \sqrt{f'(x)} \mathrm dx$. As alluded to in the comment, you will probably be disappointed to know that there is no such connection. Unfortunately integrals rarely work out this nicely.

Indeed, $\int \sqrt{f(x)} \mathrm dx$ may be *completely* different from $\int f(x) \mathrm dx$. For example:

$$\int (1 - x^3) \mathrm dx$$

is elementary and a polynomial itself, but:

$$\int \sqrt{1 - x^3} \mathrm dx$$

can only be resolved in terms of the elliptic integrals. (but has nice definite integrals over eg. $[0,1]$ with the aid of the $\Gamma$ function)

It ultimately boils down to the properties of $f'$. Certain $f'$s will resolve nicely, for example squares of functions with known antiderivatives, or in general even powers of nice functions, (eg. $\sqrt{f'(x)} = \text{polynomial} \cdot \sin x$ which will fall out, eventually, by parts) others will have unwieldly elementary antiderivatives, (eg. reciprocals of very high-order polynomials, which will eventually decompose into partial fractions and admit elementary anti-derivatives) or none at all (eg. $\frac {\sin x} x$).

Predicting whether a function has an elementary antiderivative is a question in differential algebra and is not an easy question at all. I don't have the background to understand it, but there is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative) that addresses the topic.