# Example of how to classify a function's field in Liouville's theorem?

Tags: differential-algebra

In building off of this question [Can anyone show an example of going through Liouville's differential algebra theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346606/can-anyone-show-an-example-of-going-through-liouvilles-differential-algebra-the)

I'm slowly starting to understand more components of [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) after organizing what I do and don't know, writing notes and looking back through the theorem again.

But, just when I thought I'd finally figured something out about it, I hit a roadblock.

Let's say I start with the field of rational functions $C(x)$ and I want to work with this to build my starting-field $\mathbb{F}.$

Now, I'm given an element $a \in \mathbb{F}$ where $a = e^{\sqrt{\ln(x)-1}}$ and I suppose $\int{a}$ belongs to some elementary field extension $\mathbb{G}$ of $\mathbb{F}.$

My confusion and question is, what field extensions were necessary to construct $a$ so that I can begin applying Liouville's theorem and adding extensions to check $\int a$?

The reason I'm confused is, rational functions are always the singular go-to example for this theorem. So, I figure that if $a$ belongs to a differential field, it must be $C(x,\ln(x),e^x,\sqrt{x})$ but I'm worried this is incorrect! The reason being, these are functions rational in the listed variables, $\frac{P(x,\ln(x),e^x,\sqrt{x})}{Q(x,\ln(x),e^x,\sqrt{x})}$. This says nothing about *composites* of these functions in of itself! So if I'm given a function like this, what field extension can I work with other than that of $a$ itself?

And, if I have to add finite field extensions, how could I ever see ahead and know whether it's possible or impossible to add such extensions? Supposedly this is what Liouville's theorem addresses but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions to build $e^\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1}$ from $F_0 = \mathbb{C}(x)$ are:

1. Make a logarithmic extension $\ln(x)$ to $F_0$ to get $F_1 = \mathbb{C}(x, \ln(x))$.
2. Now $\ln(x) - 1 \in F_1$; make an algebraic extension $\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1}$ to $F_1$ get a field $F_2$.
3. Now $\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1} \in F_2$; make an exponential extension $e^\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1}$ to $F_2$ to get a field $F_3$.

Now $F_3$ is your starting field containing $e^\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1}$.

Note that at each stage you can adjoin an exponential, logarithm, or radical (or more generally, any algebraic extension) using any elements you had in the previous stage. You don't go back to $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

The above only describes *field* extensions, not *differential* field extensions, which is what you actually need. To make a differential field extension you also need to specify the derivatives of the new elements you are adjoining. This is done with the usual rules of calculus.

For example, when you adjoin $\ln(x)$ to $\mathbb{C}(x)$, you specify that its derivative is $1/x$, and then all other functions in $F_1$ are differentiated by using the usual rules of calculus.  Similarly when you adjoin the $\ln$ of some other element, say $\ln u$ for $u \in F$ then you specify that $(\ln u)' = u'/u$.

Regarding the last comment, yes you are correct that field extensions here do not give composites. They only give rational functions in the new adjoined element, as is always the case for all field extensions (ignoring derivatives).

Comment: Okay, so it's just a limitation in the way field extensions work that they don't include compositing, and thus I need to add a field extension for $e^{\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1}}$ itself all as one variable. Is there a way the $\sqrt{\ln(x) - 1}$ can be generalized to $\sqrt{\ln(x) - c_1}.$?

If I need to manually guess at what field extensions to add, how could Liouville's theorem ever tell me ahead of time whether an antiderivative is elementary or not?

Comment: If $c_1$ denotes a complex number then it is exactly the same as above except you replace $\ln(x) - 1$ by $\ln(x) - c_1$ everywhere.

Comment: Also I don't know what you mean by "manually guess". You can always systematically build up extensions step by step as I did above, to get the function you want. There's really no guessing involved.

Comment: Sorry, I meant guessing at what field extensions to add to check whether $\int a$ is among them.

Comment: Liouville's theorem limits the search space of extensions for elementary antiderivatives to logarithmic extensions of elements in your starting field $F$. In particular, no tiered extensions like above are needed to get from $F$ to a field $G$ where an elementary antiderivative might be found. But it isn't some magical tool that will eliminate the need to do calculations. If $G$ exists, you might find it by guessing. If $G$ does not exist, you will need to do a (sometimes very difficult) calculation to prove that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, thank you for explaining. I might ask you at some point about examples of going through those calculations but I'll try doing some more reading first and asking another question. Do you know where the "differential" relations come into play? If one extends from $C(x)$ to $C(x,\ln(x)),$ where does $y' = u'/u$ come up?

Comment: Also when you say "adjoin", you don't mean composites do you? For instance, creating field extensions $C(x)$ to $C(x,\ln(x),\sin(x))$ wouldn't itself give you a function like $\ln(\sin(x))$ would it, since that is not rational in $\ln(x)$ or $\sin(x)$ and is instead it's own new type of function?

Comment: Please see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining Ted, I appreciate your help. Sorry if this is too many questions, but this article https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral mentions Liouville's theorem was "reproven" in purely algebraic terms. Is there a name for a theorem besides Liouville's theorem that accomplishes the same goal?

Comment: I don't know of any other name for it.