# How to solve $e^{ax} + e^{b(x - t)} = 2$?

Tags: exponential-function

I'm trying to solve an equation, but can't find any fitting formula or algorithm.

$$e^{ax} + e^{b(x - t)} = 2, t > 0$$

At the moment, I'm using an approximate solution, but my intuition tells me there *may* be an analytical one, however, it seems that I don't know how to solve this equation by myself. Can you help me with this? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** I'm looking for a solution for $x$.

**EDIT 2:** I hope I'm right at least here:

- When $a = 0$ and $b = 0$, $x$ may be anything.
- When $a = 0$ and $b \neq 0$, $x = t$.
- When $a \neq 0$ and $b = 0$, $x = 0$.
- When $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, the function on the left is increasing, and there's one $x > 0$.
- When $a < 0$ and $b < 0$, the function on the left is decreasing, and there's one $x < t$.
- When $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, and they have opposite signs, there're three possibilities:

  - if $f(\frac{bt}{b - a}) > 2$, there's no $x$;
  - if $f(\frac{bt}{b - a}) = 2$, there's one $x = \frac{bt}{b - a}$;
  - if $f(\frac{bt}{b - a}) < 2$, there're $x_1 < \frac{bt}{b - a}$ and $x_2 > \frac{bt}{b - a}$.

Comment: I would be surprised if it had a closed form solution for general $a,b,t$. But I don't have a quick reference from the top of my head and proving that something is cannot be expressed in "closed form" can be hard to prove. Cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative/265884#265884) for comparison.

Comment: You are trying to solve for what?  I can easily solve for $a$, or for $b$, or for $t$.  Only solving for $x$ will be a problem.

Comment: @GEdgar Right, exactly, it's for $x$, this's why it's such a problem.

Comment: @ThomasPreu Now I also think that there may be no a general analytical solution. Maybe, I was tricked by this equation's seeming simplicity.

Comment: What are the signs of $a$ and $b$ ? This is a key point to clarify

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The point is their signs can be anything.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that if a=nb, then setting $z=e^{bx}$ and $c=e^{-bt}$, the equation simplifies to $z^n+cz=2$. Even in this case, the problem seems intractable for large values of n.