# What makes a non-elementary integral non-elementary?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I was looking over the popular non-elementary integrals like the gaussian and fresnels, and I saw that there were some patterns. They all of course do share the trait of being impossible to express algebraically, or trigonometrically, logarithmically, etc.

So I'm curious: is there another specific trait of these functions that they all share that makes them impossible to integrate?

Comment: This question is probably too vague to give a satisfying answer.

Comment: The answer is essentially the Risch algorithm, though it's not especially intuitive.

Comment: What you are looking for is the topic of [differential algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-algebra). See for example [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative).

Comment: @jjagmath perhaps to someone more versed in mathematics it seems to be so, but to me, the question is simple: I see this rule that all functions we can't integrate abide by. Are there others?

Comment: @ian alright I'll check it out thank you

Comment: @LeeMosher ah ok, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Integrating is much harder than derivating and we soon arrive at expressions that have no closed form antiderivate. Even a product of two functions with antiderivates is too much in general.

Comment: @Mathewpotao "I see this rule that all functions we can't integrate abide by." Which rule do you see? I don't see a similarity between $x^x$ and $\cos(\cos(x))$

Comment: @jjagmath I explained that in the original comment. I was curious as to what other properties these functions shared, if any.