# How to $\int e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int e^{-x^2} dx$$
How do we calculate this integration?

Comment: ... this function does not have an antiderivative given in terms of what are called elementary functions. See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239105/special-integrals If you REALLY want a formula, an antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ is given by $F(x)=\int_a^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$.

Comment: An other question would be not to look for the anti-derivative, but for the result of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x²}dx$

Answer (score 4):

Using the series expansion
\begin{align}
e^{-x^{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{2n}}{n!}
\end{align}
then the integral has the form
\begin{align}
\int e^{- x^{2}} \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{2n+1}}{n! \, (2n+1)}.
\end{align}
The series presented here is defined as the series for the error function and the integral is given by
\begin{align}
\int e^{- x^{2}} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \, erf(x).
\end{align}

Comment: I was about to type this solution using Taylor series, good job @Leucippus :)

Answer (score 3):

We can calculate the value of integral over $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

Let $A=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} \, dy$.

$A^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} \, dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} e^{-y^2} \, dxdy$ (since $x,y$ are independent).
Then you can change to polar coordinate to evaluate the double integral.
Since $e^{-x^2}>0$, we take square root to get the final result.

Comment: The antiderivative does exist, it's just not expressible in elementary terms.

Comment: You are right. I will modify my answer. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.