# How do I do a finite expansion of $\int e^{x^2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a way to make a finite expression of the integral of e to the x-squared. How can I go about this? 
$$\int e^{x^2} \, dx$$

Comment: Can't be done. There is no closed form expression for this indefinite integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function and the almost identical question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965378/how-to-int-e-x2-dx?rq=1

Comment: We typically say "expressed in terms of elementary functions" instead of "finite expression" because otherwise you could just say that $\mathrm{erf}(x)$ (times some constant) is a finite expression for the antiderivative.

Comment: You have expressed this antiderivative using a finite number of symbols.  Thus, you have indeed given a "finite expression" of it.

Comment: Can you help me with an expansion of this problem then?